# removing trailing backslashes moves to front of the subdirectory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I added this line to my .htaccess file to remove trailing backslashes:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/$ /$1
```

but it causes the backslash to move to the back of the sub-directory (in front of the domain).

so if I type: `localhost/subfolder/`

into the address bar and press enter the result is this:

```
localhost//subfolder
```

I have also tried

`RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]`

but this had the same issue (and others). Anyone know why this happens.Thank you for reading

p.s. I am using apache2.4.4

Comment: Sigh. / is a slash (or forward slash). \ is a backslash. Please use the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since URI in `RedirectMatch` starts with a leading slash, you can use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/$ $1
```

**But better is to use `mod_rewrite` rule to exclude directories from this rule:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I used the rewiterule, and it works great, the one I had before kept messing up. but this works perfectly. Thank you very much for your answer.